# How to calculate full height of a scroll viewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I am using a scroll viewer in my xaml page. When i display lot of entries in this viewer it starts showing a scroll bar which is fine and desirable. But while exporting that page in jpeg format i need to show all entries in one image. Hence i am planning to increase its size just enough to make scroll bar disappear.
Chalange i am facing with this is that i can not calculate exactly how much do i need to increase its height so that it can accomodate all entries without showing scroll bar.
Thanks in advance.

-- Lalit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried if ViewportHeight / ViewportWidth or ScrollableHeight / ScrollableWidth suits your needs?

I would however suggest the following:

- Set **MinHeight**, **MinWidth**.
- Make sure both scrollbar visibility is set to Auto. By default it is Auto.
- The scroll viewer will expand as much as it can & then only show the
  scrollbars.
- The maximum size is defined by **MaxHeight**, **MaxWidth**.
- The **MaxHeight / MaxWidth** is always lesser than equal to what the parent
  allows.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want [`ScrollViewer.ExtentWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.extentwidth.aspx) and [`ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.extentheight.aspx).

Comment: Hi Kent,
Sorry to say but ExtentHeight is not giving me actual height it would desire to list all elements without scroll bar. :(